# Grails 3.0.6 - cannot run on Windows 7

Tags: grails, gradle

I'm having the same issue as https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/656. Is there a known workaround?

Comment: There is a related issue on the page that you have provided and the related issue has been solved.

https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1420

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply it. Do I put "[compileGroovy, compileTestGroovy]*.groovyOptions.fork = false" somewhere?